# am trying to insert more than one row into the mysql database

Tags: php

When i `var_dump($q)`, I can see the records that is to be inserted into the mysql database, but when I try to do this `$result = mysqli_query($con,$q);`, the system is not returning an error message neither is the record inserted.

```
<?php

$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "troubleshoot_db") or 
die(mysqli_error("Couldn't Establish a Connection"));

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{   

    $Grade = $_POST['Grade'];

    foreach( $Grade as $key => $v )
    {
        $fault_code = $key;
            $q = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO `history_tb` VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', $v['troubleshoot_type'] , $v['troubleshoot_result'], $v['possible_solution'], $v['reg_id'], $v['date']);
        //var_dump($q);
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    }   
}                       

?>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will also prevent any quoting issues you may be having.**

Comment: Please use the title for a short description, and your issue with full details in the body of the message. You don't explain what the issue is, nor do you check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to tackle before anything else.

1. Using prepared statements
2. Since we are using prepared statements, make use of this functionality for inserting multiple values.

Change your code into the following (only amended inside the if statement):

```
<?php

$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "troubleshoot_db") or 
die(mysqli_error("Couldn't Establish a Connection"));

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{   
    $Grade = $_POST['Grade'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `history_tb` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); //Prepare the sql command

    foreach ($Grade as $key => $v ) 
    {
        // Assuming all are strings for now
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $v['troubleshoot_type'] , $v['troubleshoot_result'], $v['possible_solution'], $v['reg_id'], $v['date']); // Bind the values in order to the ?'s
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute the completed sql command
    }

    $stmt->close(); // Close the database connection
}                       

?>
```

What we are doing here is saying my SQL is

```
INSERT INTO `history_tb` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
```

now loop through your array and call this SQL with the parameters given at each section of the loop.

This solves the first two issues of not using prepared statements and looping when using prepared statements.

Try this and lets see if records get inserted

I'd also check that the foreach is correct, maybe it needs to be

`foreach ($Grade as $v)`

but without seeing the data I can't confirm.

You can also take this further to add error handling:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `history_tb` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) 
{
    foreach ($Grade as $key => $v ) 
    {
        // Assuming all are strings for now
        // Bind the values in order to the ?'s or log error
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $v['troubleshoot_type'] , $v['troubleshoot_result'], $v['possible_solution'], $v['reg_id'], $v['date']))
        {
            die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }

        // Execute the completed sql command or log error
        if (!$stmt->execute()) 
        {
            die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
    }

    $stmt->close(); // Close the database connection
}
else 
{
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
```

Edit: added error handling

Comment: let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`( `name`, `address`) VALUES ('jony', 'test1'),('bob', 'test2')";
mysql_query($query);

Comment: // same time multiple record insert in database